# Annotating Nested ADT in Haskell with Additional Data

Tags: haskell

While writing a compiler in Haskell, I have come across a particular issue a couple times now while working with nested data types.  I will have an ADT defined something like

```
data AST = AST [GlobalDecl]

data GlobalDecl = Func Type Identifier [Stmt] | ...

data Stmt = Assign Identifier Exp | ...

data Exp = Var Identifier | ...
```

While performing some transformation on the AST, I might want to briefly carry around some extra data with variables that are used with in an expression. All of the options for doing this that I have considered so far seem to be fairly awkward. I could make a new data type:

```
data Exp' = Var' Identifier ExtraInfo | ...
```

but this means I would need a new definitions `Stmt'`, `GDecl'`, in order to form the slightly changed `AST'`. Another option is to add another data constructor to the original `Exp`, but only use it in that one particular part of the program:

```
data Exp = Var Identifier | Var' Identifier ExtraInfo | ...
```

If you do this, the typechecker can no longer prevent you from mistakenly using `Var'` in some other part the program.
A third option would be to simply keep the extra information around all the time, even though it has no relevance to the rest of the program:

```
data Exp = Var Identifier ExtraInfo | ...
```

Doable, but it's ugly, particularly if you only need the extra information briefly. For now I have just been putting the extra info in a `Map Indentifier ExtraInfo`, and carrying it around with the `AST`, either explicitly or via the state monad. This can get awkward fast, if, for instance, you need to annotate different occurances of the same `Identifier` with different info.

Does anyone have any elegant techniques for annotating nested data types?

Comment: Maybe try `data Exp a = Var Identifier a | ...`? Then functions that can pass-through annotations but don't actually use them would be polymorphic in the `a`, ones that can't handle annotations would use `Exp ()`, to annotate you have functions of type `Exp () -> Exp ExtraInfo`, and your transformations that need the extra info would use `Exp ExtraInfo`. It's basically the "keep it around all the time" option, but with the type checker able to enforce the phases where you're using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make all of your types more polymorphic, like this:

```
data AST a = AST a
data GlobalDecl t i s = Func t i [s] | ...
data Stmt i e = Assign i e | ...
data Exp a = Var a | ...
```

then you can temporarily instantiate them with a tuple - e.g. `Exp (Int, Identifier)` - for intermediate computations. If necessary, you can make `newtype`s, for the concrete types above, for convenience.

Answer (score 4):

One option to tag a structure with extra data is to use a higher kinded type parameter. If you only ever need to tag variables, you can do e.g.

```
data AST f = AST [GlobalDecl f]
data GlobalDecl f = Func Type Identifier [Stmt f] | ...
data Stmt = Assign Identifier (Exp f) | ...
data Exp f = Var (f Identifier) | ...
```

This is similar to what Peter suggested but instead of making the types fully generic it  only parametricizes the part you want to vary.

You'll get your original, untagged structure with `AST Identity` or you can have a type like `AST ((,) ExtraInfo)` which would turn `Var (f Identifier)` into `Var (ExtraInfo, Identifier)`.

If you need to tag every level of the AST with some extra information (e.g. token positions), you could even define the data type as

```
data AST f = AST [f (GlobalDecl f)]
data GlobalDecl f = Func (f (Type f)) (f (Identifier f)) [f (Stmt f)] | ...
data Stmt f = Assign (f (Identifier f)) (f (Exp f)) | ...
data Exp f = Var (f (Identifier f)) | ...
```

Now `AST ((,) ExtraInfo)` would contain extra information at every branching point in the syntax tree (granted, working with the above structure will get a bit cumbersome).

Comment: Hmm... This is doable. Though, as you say, it will get awkward quickly, particularly as things are nested deeply. I do like that it allows one to enforce which functions are allowed to accept the augmented types.